# best version for HP Mini 110 1030NR

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, usb

I have a HP Mini110 1030NA with an Atom N270 1.60 GHz and 1 gig of RAM.  Currently running XP with no issues other than not much can be used with XP anymore.  What version of Ubuntu will work on it if the XP is removed, and can I download that onto a Sandisk Cruzer or similar USB stick?  I still have 127GB of hard drive left even with XP still on there.

Comment: I have an HP mini 110c-1100. Mine is 32 bit, if yours is and you want Ubuntu or flavors, grab a 18.04 Lubuntu iso (they abandoned 32 bit after that). It works...ok but can't really run a modern browser very well. When 18.04 goes EOL there's still a 32 bit Debian I'll go to. It's mostly sentiment now, it was my first Linux computer.

Comment: You've already got a comment from a user of your box, but I'll add I used an `asus eepc 1000HE (intel atom n270, 1gb, intel mobile 945gse integrated)`, wireless RT2790` in testing Lubuntu up to 19.04 (18.10 & 19.04 are now EOL, so 18.04 LTS is the only still supported), and Xubuntu up to 19.04.  I'd opt for Lubuntu/LXDE as well; just like @OrganicMarble suggested (1gb RAM isn't much; worse if it's shared with video ram)) ; 8-August-2020 is my last recorded test of 18.04.5 released that month.